# How to run multiple SQL statements in parallel in an Oracle stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

Is there a way where I can run DML statements on different tables in parallel on a  Oracle database?

By in parallel I mean if I have two insert statements on table A and table B, they should both be executed at the same time (not sequentially).

Comment: Run them from two different connections

Comment: If It is possible, Try `INSERT ALL` or `INSERT FIRST`

Comment: @Prathamesh Do you mean the exact same statement, like in the duplicate question, or two different statements run concurrently?  I have a feeling this question was incorrectly marked as a duplicate - let me know and I'll raise a flag if necessary.

Comment: @Jon Heller Two different tables with two different statements inserting concurrently.